# Zend Framework 1.12 - Plugin by name 'Paginationcontrol' was not found in the registry

Tags: zend-framework

I have got error messages when i m load view all student controller

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:
```

Message: Plugin by name 'Paginationcontrol' was not found in the registry; used paths: Admin_View_Helper_: /home/aiengine/public_html/zend/psc_app_final_4/application/modules/admin/views/helpers/ ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:./views/helpers/

**viewallstudentAction**

```
 public function viewallstudentsAction() {
     $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();


    $selection = $db->select()->from('tblstudents');
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($selection);
    $paginator->setcurrentpagenumber($this->_getparam('page', 1));
    $paginator->setItemcountperpage('10');
    $paginator->setpagerange('5');
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;

    $searchstudent_form = new Admin_For`enter code here`m_Searchstudent();
    $this->view->searchstudent_form = $searchstudent_form;
}

-------------
**viewallstudents.phtml**

<div id="view-content">
    <div class="row">           

        <div class="col-md-3">              
            <div class="form-group">                    
                <?php echo $this->searchstudent_form; ?>
            </div>       

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <br/>
            <?php echo $this->paginationcontrol($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'students/index.phtml') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="button" id="del_student_confirm" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <table class="table table-hover" id="viewallstudents">
            <th>
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" > 
                </label>

            </th>
            <th> studentID</th>
            <th> name</th>
            <th> sex</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <tr id="search_result" class="success">


            </tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($this->paginator as $record) {
                ?>

                <tr id="<?php echo $record['studentID']; ?>">
                    <td>
                        <div id="c_b">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="<?php echo $record['studentID']; ?>" name="studentID[]"> 
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $record['studentID']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $record['name']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $record['sex']; ?></td>
                    <td><a id='update' href="<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'editstudent', 'studentID' => $record['studentID'], 'name' => $record['name'], 'name' => $record['name'], 'sex' => $record['sex']), null, true); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/img/edit.png"/></a> </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Model Display-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4><img src="<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/img/warning.png"/> &nbsp;Are you sure you wish to delete?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete_me">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">

                <h4><img src="<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/img/warning.png"/> &nbsp;Are you sure you wish to Update?</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="update_me">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

//    $("form").submit(function(event) {
//
//        event.preventDefault();
//    });

    $('#checkAll').click(function() {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    //identify selected checkbox count



    $("#del_student_confirm").click(function() {

        var searchIDs = $('#inlineCheckbox1:checked').map(function() {

            return $(this).val();

        });
        if (searchIDs.length > 0) {

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }


        //delete functionality'

        $("#delete_me").click(function() {

            var searchIDs = [];
            $('#inlineCheckbox1:checked').each(function() {
                searchIDs.push(this.value);
            });

            //Identify Selected Checked boxes and clear all items

            $.each(searchIDs, function(index, value) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/admin/students/deletestudents/studentID/" + value,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                        $('table#viewallstudents tr#' + value).remove();
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    }
                });
            });

            $.each(searchIDs, function(index, value) {
                searc.splice(index, value);

            });
        });
    });

    //Search Function
//    $("#student_name").keyup(function() {
//
//        alert($("#student_name").val());
//    });
    $("#autocomplete").keypress(function() {

        var value = $("#autocomplete").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/admin/students/searchstudents/",
            data: {student_name: value},
            success: function(response) {
                //  alert(response.empty);

                if (response.empty === "0") {

                } else {
                    var check_Box = "<div id='c_b'>" +
                            "<label class='checkbox-inline'>" +
                            "<input type='checkbox' id='inlineCheckbox1' value=" + response.studentID + " name='studentID[]'>" +
                            "</label>" +
                            "</div>";

                    var update_icon = "<a id=\"update\" href='<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/admin/students/editstudent/studentID/" + response.studentID + "/name/" + response.name + "/sex/" + response.sex + "'><img src='<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/img/edit.png'/></a>";
                    var html_content = "<td>";

                    html_content += check_Box;
                    html_content += "</td>";

                    html_content += "<td>";
                    html_content += response.studentID;
                    html_content += "</td>";

                    html_content += "<td>";
                    html_content += response.name;
                    html_content += "</td>";

                    html_content += "<td>";
                    html_content += response.sex;
                    html_content += "</td>";

                    html_content += "<td>";
                    html_content += update_icon;
                    html_content += "</td>";




                    $("#search_result").html(html_content);
                    //$('table#viewallstudents tr#' + response.studentID).remove();
                }

            }
        });


    });

    $('#student_name').keyup(function() {
        if ($('#student_name').val().length === 0) {
            alert('empty');
        }
    });



</script>

-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says is all ,

use this,

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'students/index.phtml'); ?>
```

and it would work.
you are using small 'c' in paginationControl.